# How to see if git binary is using openssl or gnutls?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, libcurl, gnutls

I'm trying to debug a strange issue with git clone, https protocol, of one specific repo using Ubuntu with a corporate proxy. The same thing works in CentOS, Fedora distros but not on Ubuntu or Debian in our environment.

Apparently in Ubuntu packages git is using gnutls, but on other platform openssl. However building from sources, even on Ubuntu, uses openssl according to [this](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/git/issues/40).

Is there a way for me to check from a given git installation which one the binary is using? Some output that would tell me?

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245292/how-can-i-make-git-tell-curl-to-use-openssl-instead-of-gnutls-without-rebuilding) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers) are related, but both talk about changing it either runtime or build time - at this point I would just need the info about which one it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ cd /usr/lib/git-core
$ ./git --version
git version 1.9.1
$ ldd git-http-fetch | grep libcurl
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007f8d5dcdf000)

$ cd /usr/libexec/git-core
$ ./git --version
git version 2.8.1
$ ldd git-http-fetch | grep libcurl
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007f6bd1e42000)
```

So apparently both my operating-system supplied version and my self-compiled version are against gnutls.

this is what openssl output looks like when the same command is run, there is no `libcurl-gnutls`, but

```
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fe96267e000)
```

looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645007/365237), seems git at runtime is just using whatever libcurl the system is set up to use, so my question was a bit misleading. Anyway, this answer is correct in the sense that it will tell which one is being used.

Comment: Maybe it's not relevant, but even if I compile using the flag --with-openssl and when using ldd git-http-fetch, I see that library is also used:

libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f7f8b8de000)

Does it really uses OpenSSL instead of GNU TLS?

Comment: @SimonTremblay did you read my answer? "seems git at runtime is just using whatever libcurl the system is set up to use,"